# how to get the fully qualified name of node in an AST?

Tags: java, parsing, tree, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm using the ASTParser to parse some code and I need the fully qualified name of nodes. I tried the following and it is not working. It still gives me the simple name only.

```
public static void parse(String str)
{
 ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
 parser.setSource(str.toCharArray());


 parser.setResolveBindings(true);
 parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
 parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);


 Map options = JavaCore.getOptions();
 JavaCore.setComplianceOptions(JavaCore.VERSION_1_7, options);
 parser.setCompilerOptions(options);

 CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

 cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

    public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration node) {

        System.out.println(node.getName().getFullyQualifiedName());
        return true;
    }
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Type `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Name` is part of the AST structure and thus only knows about what's written in source code. If source code contains a simple name, that will be what this node contains.

To get the qualified name of the **resolved** type you need to request a **binding** using one of

- `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AbstractTypeDeclaration.resolveBinding()`
- `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Name.resolveBinding()`
- ...

On the resulting `ITypeBinding`, `getQualifiedName()` should yield the name you are looking for.

I see that you already call `parser.setResolveBindings(true);` so you should be all set.